# How to maintain data entered/Selected on Web forms without saving it

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

We are creating an ASP.Net application. We use Jquery/javascript for clienside, MySQL as backend.
Now client want to implement functionality like, **Suppose there is Customer form, We fill few details on it, & without saving we click on Vendor Form, Now when we again return on Customer page, The data which we last time enterer should be as it is?**
How to achieve this functionality? As our project is already completed , How to add this functionality with fewer changes?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: HTML5's sessionStorage/localStorage

Comment: Sorry but we cant use HTML5 , please suggest any other option?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using .net, you could look into [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR) to push data to a temp table in your database, OR, if you want to support HTML5, you could try using [`localStorage();`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/).

Answer (score 1):

You could save the data in a cookie whenever the text changes.  When you submit the data, delete the cookie.

Something like this :- http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/setcookie/#.Uf8tPpLdfzg

except you wouldn't do it on submit but whenever any text changes

Comment: Means we need to add cookies in overall application, On each page?

Comment: yep.... but you don't have a lot of options, either some kind of local storage, or ajaxing ( or websockets ) data back to the server and the server having some way of storing the state.

Comment: Okay. I will try when get back to work, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you support HTML5, you can use localstorage to temporarily store the form data.
Here's a quick guide on how to use it: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

For older browsers, there are many libraries out there that give you fallback capabilities. Here's a good one: http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/

Comment: We can't use HTML5 option, so I will try to do it with amplifyjs